# How do I export the dependent libraries to a directory for deployment in gradle?

Tags: build-automation, gradle

I need to deploy my code to another machine. How do I export the dependent jars to a lib directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the correct way, but to copy the jars to a lib directory I do the following:

```
/**
 * Copies the dependencies to the lib directory in preparation for them to be added to a jar file
 */
 task copyRuntimeDependencies(dependsOn: configurations.runtime.buildArtifacts, type: Copy) 
  {
    into('build/output/lib')
    from configurations.runtime
    from configurations.runtime.allArtifacts*.file
  }
```

Comment: Hmm.  This doesn't seem to work any more with Gradle 1.5.  I think there is a type in there somewhere.

Comment: It is always a good idea to check the gradle cookbook: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRADLE/Cookbook#Cookbook-Includeallruntimedependencies

Answer (score 5):

Here is the way to do it with Gradle 2.x:

```
task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    // into "build/lib"
    into "lib"
    from configurations.classpath
}
```

Comment: Alternatively: You can use the type [`Sync`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.5/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Sync.html), which will also delete any items not copied over.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I like it better.  Thanks.   I needed to copy libs into a folder so that I can enable a non-Java process launcher (TFS) to start my JMeter Java process on the command line.  https://github.com/djangofan/launch-jmeter